# Read XML node attribute in PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a class with few properties. Constructor of that class getting one string attribute where is xml string read from database clob column.

```
#Powershell code
Class test
{
    [string]$prop1
    [int]$prop2
    test([string]$input)
    {
        $xml = [xml]$input
        $this.prop1 = $xml|Select-XML -XPath '/Properties/Property[@name="Validation"]'
        $this.prop2 = $xml|Select-XML -XPath '/Properties/Property[@name="Port"]'
    }
}
```

This how xml string looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><properties>
  <property name="Validation" value="yes"/>
  <property name="Port" value="636"/>
</properties>
```

I'm trying to retrieve node attribute from XML file.
The problem is that constructor doesn't assign values to the properties.
I'm not getting any data in the line below.

```
$xml|Select-XML -XPath '/Properties/Property[@name="Port"]'
```

Comment: Your xml file doesn't have `Properties` or `Property`. I has `properties` and `property`. XML is case-sensitive.

Comment: PowerShell already auto-maps to objects, there's no need to muck about with XPath. `$xml.properties.property` will give you the list of properties in a natural format. `($xml.properties.property | Where { $_.name -eq "Validation" }).value` gives you the value of `Validation`. And so on.